# Is there an oportunity to trigger python function after sheet is edited, using xlwings (vba is not allowed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

I am trying to work with Excel Workbooks in Python using xlwings. I would like to create a GUI where users can choose what they want to do by clicking a button. For example, Load an Additional Column, or something like that. The idea is:

Open a large xlsx file via xlwings.
Load data into a dataframe.
Allow users to do something (Add Columns / Sum Columns / etc.) - it should be done on the dataframe.
Save the updated dataframe to the opened xlsx file.
I would like to give users the opportunity to change values between choosing options (Add Columns / Sum Columns / etc.), but it is problematic because if I want to be sure that the dataframe and the sheet are up to date, I have to load a lot of data from the sheet to the dataframe every single time when the user chooses any option.

It takes a lot of time, so I would like to optimize the process by checking when the sheet was last edited by a user and comparing this datetime with the datetime of the pasted dataframe. However, I can't find an easy way to send the datetime of when the sheet is edited to Python each time an edit occurs. I found a solution in VBA that allows me to save the edit datetime in an additional sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim infoSheet As Worksheet
    Set infoSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INFO")
    
    Dim currentDateTime As String
    currentDateTime = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    
    infoSheet.Range("A1").Value = currentDateTime
End Sub
```

This saves the datetime every single time I edit Sheet1, but I am looking for a solution that does not involve VBA.

Comment: Use vwatchdog to monitor a change in the file?

Comment: how i can use it for checking if only one sheet is modyfied? Let's imagine that user create another tab or do smth in the file (not edit data tab), then datetime will be changed also? am i right?

Comment: I think what you want might be only available in the PRO version if its functional. Felix might have weighed in to comment but seems not. The watchdog will monitor the file for a change in file modification date/time but you would need to have a means to determine what changed.